# Ubuntu versions repository

Tags: repository

I am looking for Ubuntu 18.04.

I would like to know if releases.ubuntu.com is a legit site for downloading previous versions of Ubuntu.
Is it the official repository?

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Canonical owns the domain ubuntu.com.

It's official.